# Getting value from drop down menu in html and accessing it in php

Tags: php, html

How do I access the selected value of a drop down menu from html and get it in php? I've got a few fields like this:

```
    <html>";            
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $stuff = mysql_query($sql) or die ("An error has occured.");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stuff))
    {
        $body.= "<option>".$row['value']."</option>\n";
    }
    $body.="<html>
```

I want to take this value and use it to filter the results I get from another query. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I don't see why this would be down voted? I've searched all over and I can't find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### In your current file

You need to add form around your select element. I have also fix some of your code so that the select tags are included and the option tags actually have a value set in them!

I have also added in a submit button so you can actually send the form.

```
$body .= '<select name="filter">
       <form action="" method="post">';            
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stuff = mysql_query($sql) or die ("An error has occured.");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stuff))
{
    $value = htmlentities($row['value'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $body .= '<option value="' . $value . '">' . 
            "$value</option>\n";
}
$body .= '</select>
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>';
```

### In results.php

You now need to grab the filter from the POST values and use it in your query to filter the results like so:

```
$filter = '';
if(isset($_POST['filter'])) {
    $filter = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['filter']);
}
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `field` = '$filter'";
// you can do the rest of the code from here :)
```

### All in one file:

```
<?php
if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    $filter = '';
    if(isset($_POST['filter'])) {
        $filter = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['filter']);
    }
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `field` = '$filter'";
    // you can do the rest of the code from here :)
}

$body .= '<select name="filter">
       <form action="results.php" method="post">';            
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stuff = mysql_query($sql) or die ("An error has occured.");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stuff))
{
    $value = htmlentities($row['value'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $body .= '<option value="' . $value . '">' . 
            "$value</option>\n";
}
$body .= '</select>
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>';
```

Comment: I like how you used `mysql_real_escape_string` properly. You would really make my day if you also added the appropriate `htmlspecialchars` to your HTML output. (+1 for listening to my nagging).

Comment: @Rodin I shall not use `htmlspecialchars()`! But I will use `htmlentities()`. I was trying to keep the code changes to a minimum so that the asker could follow it more easily! :)

Comment: Thats a great answer, but is there anyway to keep the code all in one file?

Answer (score 0):

write your drop down control in html form, write javascript for form submit on open change and than you get drop down value using `$_POST['ddname']` and use it for php filter

Answer (score 0):

So when you select a value from the dropdown list you can post the value or pass it as a get variable and use it in the query to filter results